# Setting a greyscale (or monochrome) color scheme

Tags: color-management

I would like to see everything on my computer screen in grayscale (like say the kindle screen). How do I do this?

Comment: is this also available in ubuntu 14.04? I don't have the color filter option in Accessibility nor anywhere else :/
anyone?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Compiz has a few filters which supposedly can do what you want.

1. Install [Compiz Config Setting Manager](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM) from Ubuntu Software Center    or with `sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager`.
2. Run it and under Accessibility category you'll find *Color Filter* and *Opacity, Brightness and Saturation* filters.
3. There you'll be able to enable them, assign a keyboard shortcut and edit the filters' settings.

[image: Compiz Config Setting Manager]

Now, I have to admit that I wasn't able to test it since I only have Ubuntu in a virtual box without 3D acceleration, but hopfully it'll give you some pointers.

Also, please don't get too excited modifying Compiz settings - it is quite easy to break Unity by doing so. The filters I mentioned above should be quite safe though.

Comment: I can confirm that the monochrome color filter works nicely.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but what if when I install it and I only have but a few of the options? I only see "general" in the lefthand menu.

Comment: @KardNails You are more likely to get a reply by asking this as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as I personally visited this answer at first in 2022, I would recommend to see [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/s412xc/is_there_a_way_to_make_my_display_grayscale_on/) answer, where GNOME *bedtime* extension is a solution.
Works good for me as it has its own settings and not dangerous (seems like that) at all to crash your system.