# How can I turn my screen mode to grayscale?

Tags: xorg, color-management

I would like to temporarily turn my screen gray, to estimate how certain images would appear if printed with a black-and-white printer.  I think `xcalib` could do it but I don't know how.  Does anyone know how to get the desired effect?

For instance, to view inverted colors, I run `xcalib -invert -alter` to toggle the effect and it works great.  Is there a similar way to get a grayscale screen?

Comment: You won't believe it, but we already have an answer even for this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/102440/setting-a-greyscale-or-monochrome-color-scheme :)