# How can Ubuntu be made grayscale?

Tags: xorg, colors

I'd like to make everything grayscale. The utility xcalib can be used to invert the colours displayed (every colour displayed is changed to its compliment) using the following command:

```
xcalib -i -a
```

How could I make the display grayscale? Could I desaturate in some way, for example?

Thanks!

Comment: First, why? Second, can you use the monitors color controls and do it at the monitor? Third, you can adjust your color-depth but I don't know if you can do grayscale (might be b/w only).

Comment: 1: It's just a subjective preference. Sometimes I find it relaxing to view things in grayscale. 2: The displays I am using offer control over colour balance and gamma, but not saturation, so this does not appear to be possible. In any case, I want a solution that is usable on multiple different displays. 3: Yes, I note that Xcalib offers this colour balance (and gamma) control, but it does not appear to offer saturation control.

Comment: If you use Compiz you can use the solution provided here [Setting a greyscale (or monochrome) color scheme](http://askubuntu.com/questions/102440/setting-a-greyscale-or-monochrome-color-scheme).

Comment: While it appears to apply the saturation changes only to active windows (i.e., it doesn't make *everything* grayscale), this is a pretty good solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also add the following to your xorg configuration to achieve a greyscale output:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier "greyscale configuration"
    Defaultdepth 8
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth 8
        Visual "GrayScale"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

This might work depending on your video driver.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. It does not appear to work on my computer, but I have seen reports of success using this approach. I think further exploration is needed.