# display in grayscale

Tags: unity, display, colors, accessibility

I need to show my desktop in gray-scale mode.
On MacOS I can do it in accessibility mode. I tried with `compiz config` but the color filter was removed from Ubuntu 14.04.

Who can help me?

I use Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity.

Comment: Sorry not a duplicate. I misread your question.

Comment: could you repair ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **Opacity, Brightness & Saturation** plug-in.

1. Open `ccsm` Compiz manager
2. Go to Accessibility → Then enable: Opacity, Brightness & Saturation
3. Open it, Go to Saturation tab
4. Add new rule:

   Windows: `any` Value: `0`

I got all windows in grayscale only unity dash & top panel still in color, may be needs a reboot. :) sorry not the time to test that.

[image]

BTW, it is possible to get a hardware solution for VGA with just few resistors to make an RGB channels merger/mixer.

Comment: Note that you might have to install "compiz-plugins" (sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins) to have this option in ccsm.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve what you want with **xcalib** 
If it's not installed:

```
 sudo apt-get install xcalib
```

try something like

```
 xcalib -i -a

 xcalib -invert -alter

 xcalib -co 70 -a
```

To reset screen

```
 xcalib -c
```

For more info about xcalib check out http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/xcalib.1.html

or

```
xcalib -h
```

Following link may also help out [How can Ubuntu be made grayscale?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443335/how-can-ubuntu-be-made-grayscale)

Comment: Note that there's currently (at least up to Ubuntu 18.04) a bug in xorg causing xcalib to not work https://askubuntu.com/a/945565/25639