# Invert colors, change to grayscale as a toogle

Tags: xorg, display, colors

I want to toogle my screen colors (for example with keyboard shortcut)  between normal and inverted+grayscale. `xcalib -i -a` does what I need to invert them, but does not seem to be capable for making them grayscale. The answer from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125257/how-can-i-make-the-screen-black-and-white suggests that I need to change the configuration file, but how to make it as toggle?

The ideal behaviour for color changes should look like:
[image: Normal colors]
[image: Inverted colors + grayscale colors]

**Bonus**: To get it even more useful I would like to apply these color changes only for specific window (web browser, word processor, etc).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a greyscale (or monochrome) color scheme](http://askubuntu.com/questions/102440/setting-a-greyscale-or-monochrome-color-scheme)

Comment: Do you have an Nvidia graphics adapter? If so, we could build on one of the answers of the [Unix.SE] question you're linking.

Comment: You can do this in Evince with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, if your main concern is pdf files.