# Change screen to black and white for accessibility reasons

Tags: xorg, accessibility

I need help changing my screen to black and white, but in a specific way. On GIMP, you can desaturate the colours based on Lightness (2) and Luminosity (3). I need my entire screen to be converted to greyscale 'based on luminosity'. Is there a way I can do this with Xorg or some other program? [An example of how I need the colors converted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIezs.png)

Comment: Too lazy right now to copy it here. But there you go: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125257/how-can-i-make-the-screen-black-and-white

Comment: It does not appear to work. The screen's colour is unchanged and everything begins to lag

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012905/how-do-i-make-my-display-grayscale) answer your question?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/102440/setting-a-greyscale-or-monochrome-color-scheme