# How to turn display into grayscale on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu-one

[How do I make my display grayscale?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012905/how-do-i-make-my-display-grayscale#1013262)
 - alredy tried this tutorial, but the folder name doesn't allow "/" in it.

I've tried doing it through Imagemagick, but couldn't properly install it.

Newbie on Linux. Thanks.

Comment: Did you run: `sudo apt update; sudo apt install imagemagick` ?

Comment: It results in "E: Unable to locate package imagemagic
".

Comment: You spelled it wrong. The name is imagemagick not imagemagic but I have your answer below.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, install `git`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
```

**Next**, run the following commands to create the proper folder directory:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
```

It may state that the directory already exists. You can ignore this error.

**Then**, run the following command to download the extension:

```
git clone https://github.com/laerne/desaturate_all.git
```

**Finally**, run the following command to move the files to the proper directory:

```
mv desaturate_all ".local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desaturate_all@nicolas.brack.mail.be"
```

Now, you will need to restart Gnome. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then press <kbd>R</kbd> and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

You can enable the extension by browsing to https://extensions.gnome.org/local

[Click here for more information.](https://github.com/laerne/desaturate_all)

Please post any errors. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to click to click the checkmark icon to the left of the answer to mark this as the accepted solution. Otherwise, post any errors. Thanks!

Comment: When I enter: sudo apt install git

It results in:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.

(continues in next comment)

Comment: (continuing)

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-man (> 1:2.17.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-man (< 1:2.17.1-.) but it is not going to be installed
 stacer : Depends: gconf2
          Depends: gconf-service
          Depends: python but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: So I type: apt --fix-broken install

It results in:
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

So I don't know what else to do.

Comment: @broade You do not have permission because you need to use `sudo` when you run the command so run this instead: `sudo apt --fix-broken install` Please post any more errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a GNOME Extension for this. You can install this extension with one click form [Desaturate All GNOME Extention by laerne](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1102/desaturate-all/). When you install extension, a picture icon appear on the taskbar. When you click, all desktop went to greyscale.